# add parameters to get in when mod_rewrite is already there

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, hyperlink

I would like to pass an additional parameter using the a href tag in a link which is already handled by this rule in htaccess

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.*
 RewriteRule .* . [F,L]
 RewriteBase /

 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/contact.html         contact.php?ln=$1 [L]
```

the link I would like to use is this

```
/en/contact.html?t=Build 5
```

then to the page should `contact.php?ln=en&t=Build 5`.

If I print in contac.php the $ _GET returns only ln = en.

How can I do?

Comment: _Aside:_ `/en/contact.html?t=Build 5` - You should URL encode the URL parameter values. ie. the _space_ should be URL encoded as `%20` or `+` in the query string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `[L,QSA]` in your rule, to get your parameters.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/contact.html         contact.php?ln=$1 [L,QSA]
```

See [[QSA]](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html)  (QueryStringAppend)

Comment: Thanks your suggestion solved.

Thank you